# C# Валидировать SVG программно - какие есть способы?

Tags: svg, .net-core

Как проверить SVG -содержимое на корректность и отсутствие вставок, не относящихся к этому формату? Может, библиотеки какие-то есть для .NET Core?

Comment: Почитайте тут - https://www.w3.org/wiki/SVGvalidation , svg 1.2 даже dtd схемы не имеет.

Comment: Вот есть какая-то [схема](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-SVG11-20020108/SVG.xsd). Пробуйте.